# Botium jobs stucked at ready

Tags: testing, automated-tests, chatbot

All my Test Project are stuck on "Ready".

I tried restarting containers and even "I'm Botium" is stuck on Ready without passed/failed results.

Job Log is here: https://pastebin.com/851LPCBS

In the Docker logs is:

```
2019-10-04T08:25:30.046Z botium-box-worker sending heartbeat ...
2019-10-04T08:25:30.049Z botium-box-server-agents agent.heartbeat: {"title":"heartbeat from agent b0c5b43c0f82 for group Default Group","name":"b0c5b43c0f82","group":"Default Group"}
2019-10-04T08:25:35.559Z botium-box-server-index WARNING: a socket timeout ocurred. You should increase the BOTIUMBOX_API_TIMEOUT environment variable.
2019-10-04T08:25:35.598Z botium-box-server-index WARNING: a socket timeout ocurred. You should increase the BOTIUMBOX_API_TIMEOUT environment variable.
```

Comment: The I AM BOTIUM sample is using git integration which is available in the paid editions only. The log looks lije the test cases are missing. What test sets are you using ? Does the ECHO SAMPLE work ?

Comment: Looks like there was problem with Test Case, when I wrote new one manually in Botium Box, test runs are returning results. Now it looks like there are issues with Bot Connector settings, that needs adjustment: https://pastebin.com/XVi8P0NW. Thank you.

Comment: Webdriver fails with message "HTTP method not allowed" - I would say, that the connection to the Selenium hub is not working. What happens if you are using the Integrated PhantomJS driver ?

Comment: Phantom is returning error with Element locators not visible, so looks like there are indeed problems woth connection to Selenium Hub. I'll adjust Bot configuration and try it with Phantom. Thanks

Comment: I tried to set WEBDRIVERIO_OPENBOT with JavaScript code snipped, but looks like it is not running before finding input field, why is that?
https://pastebin.com/pPM5efeK

Comment: You added WEBDRIVERIO_OPENBOT  as environment variable - pls add as capability